# Dealing with strange encoding for PHP/MySQL import

Tags: php, mysql, csv, encoding

We get a daily upload of a CSV file from a client that they say is in UTF16-LE encoding. However, when I run `iconv('UTF16-LE', 'UTF8')` on each line of the CSV file, it looks like this when going into the database:

Z�A�A�0�7�3�7

IE, there's one of those [?] things in between every character.

I tried utf8_encode and various combinations of iconv and different encoding types in order to get this to go away. Has anyone had any experience with this and how to convert an unknown or unsupported encoding into UTF8, or at least something readable by PHP and MySQL?

Comment: Are you running `iconv` by command line or with PHP? What does the string look like BEFORE it's inserted into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Half of the characters in UTF16 cannot be converted into UTF8. UTF16 takes an addition 8 bits.

UTF16 has, encoded into each string, LE or BE. Just for fun, you could try converting from UTF16 to UTF8 (no '-LE'). This would tell you if your client lied to you about LE. But it's most likely the case that the data just doesn't fit.

One solution would be to store it as byte arrays (BINARY(x)) in the database, not as text.

Comment: Even if half of the characters are unable to be converted, how likely is it that any of these characters are actually being used in the string?

Comment: knowing nothing other than the range of characters - 50%

Comment: So basically if our database is in UTF8, then we can't store a UTF16-encoded string in string format (ie, it would only work in binary format)?

Comment: That is my understanding. I recently ran into a similar issue while working at Lucidchart

Comment: Turns out they lied about LE, I just ran iconv with UTF16 and it worked fine. Thanks for your help!